# Confusion over using a gerund in a sentence

Tags: grammaticality-in-context

Is this sentence idiomatic?

> I was talking over phone during my visiting to the hospital.

If not, why is it not idiomatic?

I am using a gerund in a gerund clause after all.

Comment: There has to be an article or possessive pronoun before *phone*. (For instance, ***the***, ***a*** or ***my*** *phone*.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was talking over phone during my visit to the hospital. 
While visiting the hospital, I was talking over phone.

In '...during my visiting', the visit sounds better as a noun than visiting.

Comment: That's because _during_ goes with a noun (a period of time or an activity), not a verb. We're not supposed to offer proof-reading, but I could also point out that it's _talking over the phone_.

Comment: @KateBunting Yes.

Comment: You need to add article ‘the’ before the word ‘phone’. Read Jason Bassford comment on the main post. Here’s a guide to “artice usage”: https://www.grammarly.com/blog/articles/